# initialize std::array with 'this' pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, this

I am trying to initialize an array inside a template class and pass the `this` pointer to all elements in the array. 
This is what my classes might look like:

```
template<int NUM> class outer_class;

template<int N>
class inner_class {
  private:
   outer_class<N> *cl;
  public:
   inner_class(outer_class<N> *num) {
    cl = num;
   }
   void print_num() {
    cl->print_num();
   }

};

template<int NUM> class outer_class {
 private:
  int number = NUM;

  // --> here I basically want NUM times 'this' <-- 
  std::array<inner_class<NUM>, NUM> cl = { this, this, this, this }; 

 public:

  void print_num() {
    std::cout << number << std::endl;
  }

  void print() {
    cl[NUM - 1].print_num();
  }
};

int main() {
  outer_class<4> t;
  t.print();

  return 0;
}
```

How can I pass the `this` pointer to all elements of `inner_class` stored in the array of `outer_class` (in C++11)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, you can't have `this` like this outside of constructor or any other member function. Here you have to initialize `cl` within initializer list.

Using [delegating constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Delegating_constructor) together with [std::*_sequence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) stuff:

```
template<int NUM> class outer_class {
    ...

    template <std::size_t... Integers>
    outer_class(std::index_sequence<Integers...>) 
    : cl{(static_cast<void>(Integers), this)...}
    {}

public:
    outer_class(/* whatever */) : outer_class(std::make_index_sequence<NUM>{}) {}
};
```

Side notes:

- Your `print` member functions should be marked `const` as they don't modify your members.
- `cl[NUM - 1].print_num();` you might want to use [`std::array::back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/back).

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if the sequence constructor were private?

Comment: @O'Neil Thx for your answer, nice and easy

Answer (score 4):

You could use some helper functions and then initialize the member using these functions, e.g.:

```
template <std::size_t I, class T>
T copy(T t) { return t; }

template <class T, std::size_t... Is>
constexpr std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)> copy_n(T const& t, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return {copy<Is>(t)... };
}

template <class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::array<T, N> copy_n(T const& t) {
    return copy_n(t, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

Then in your class:

```
std::array<inner_class<NUM>, NUM> cl;

outer_class() : cl(copy_n<inner_class<NUM>, NUM>(this)) { }
```

Note:

- **[to be verified]** you cannot use `this` in default member initializer, so you need to have a custom constructor;
- you need to explicitly specify `inner_class<NUM>` as the first template parameter for `copy_n`, because otherwize `T` will be deduced as `outer_class<NUM>*`, and while there is an implicit conversion from `outer_class<NUM>*` to `inner_class<NUM>`, there is no conversion from `std::array<outer_class<NUM*>, NUM>` to `std::array<inner_class<NUM>, NUM>`;
- if you are using C++11 and not 14, or `clang`, you might get a warning on the `return` of `copy_n`, you can get rid of it by adding an extra pair of brackets `{}`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks, I was actually wondering about that but did not find the information by myself... will update the answer.

Comment: Or maybe it can? [Seems to work fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c9adcb807cfa68a).

Comment: This seems pretty good, but is there a c++11 compatible version of std::make_index_sequence?

Comment: @MikevanDyke Not directly, you can find implementation on the web, e.g. https://gist.github.com/jappa/62f30b6da5adea60bad3

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I cannot find anything directly related to this in the standard (can't find a lot of stuff regarding default-member initializer actually... ), but what I understand is that `this` should only be valid in member functions, so this would not be valid in this case.

Comment: I've used `this` in NSDMI before.  It worked as desired/expected.

Comment: @Holt Thx a lot for your answer and the provided link for index_sequence.